# Variables impossibly set as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This is very odd behavior (which appears only to happen on Chrome on a Mac) where much of the code appears to be skipped entirely and variables that should have values are set as "undefined".

Here is a screenshot from Chrome's developer tools. Note that line 817 was never hit! However 833 was hit and what we are looking at is an exception that was hit and I looked up the call stack to find this mess. Also note that the variables "loc", "lon" and "tc" are all undefined, which should not be possible as they have each have been evaluated on lines 822, 823/824, and 827/831. If there was an error in the calculations the values of these variables should be NaN from my understanding.

[image: screenshot from Chrome Developer Tools]

Here is the actual code:

```
function getCircle2(latin, lonin, radius) {
    var locs = new Array();
    var lat1 = latin * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var lon1 = lonin * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var d = radius / 3956;
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x <= 360; x++) {
        var tc = (x / 90) * Math.PI / 2;
        var lat = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(tc));
        lat = 180.0 * lat / Math.PI;
        var lon;
        if (Math.cos(lat1) == 0) {
            lon = lonin; // endpoint a pole
        }
        else {
            lon = ((lon1 - Math.asin(Math.sin(tc) * Math.sin(d) / Math.cos(lat1)) + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI)) - Math.PI;
        }
        lon = 180.0 * lon / Math.PI;
        var loc = new VELatLong(lat, lon);
        locs.push(loc);
    }
    return locs;
}
```

Can anyone shine some light on this wizardry? Why would a breakpoint be ignored and variables have incorrect values only in Chrome on a Mac!?

EDIT:

It appears that I have fixed the bug. All I did was isolate the breaking code in its own function, call the function once, if it threw an exception I called it again and it seems to work 100% of the time. I am still very curious at what was the root cause of the issue.

```
//new function to isolate the exception
function getCirclePointOnRadius(deg, lat1, lon1, d, attempt) {
    attempt = attempt || 1;
    var maxAttempts = 2;
    try {
        var tc = (deg / 90) * Math.PI / 2;
        var lat = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(tc));
        lat = 180.0 * lat / Math.PI;
        var lon;
        if (Math.cos(lat1) == 0) {
            lon = lonin; // endpoint a pole
        }
        else {
            lon = ((lon1 - Math.asin(Math.sin(tc) * Math.sin(d) / Math.cos(lat1)) + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI)) - Math.PI;
        }
        lon = 180.0 * lon / Math.PI;
        var loc = new VELatLong(lat, lon);
        return loc;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log2('Error when gathering circle point "' + e + '", trying again', deg, lat1, lon1);
        if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
            return getCirclePointOnRadius(deg, lat1, lon1, ++attempt);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I replace the loop that originally held the logic (in `getCircle2`) with:

```
    for (x = 0; x <= 360; x++) {
        locs.push(getCirclePointOnRadius(x, lat1, lon1, d));
    }
```

Comment: Are you debugging with local files or on a website like jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: Yes. This is a .Net solution. The production files show the same error but uses minified javascript files.

Comment: Works well on Chrome on Windows?

Comment: Works fine on Chrome on Windows from what our QA has found and I have personally not been able to recreate the error on Windows.

Comment: Just tried running the code on mac chrome and it worked. I didn't have the VELatLong function in the code but had it log all the lat lon values.

Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) if that helps.

Comment: Since the exception is a VEException, which looks like it's defined in an external resource, I'd say that the root cause is a timing issue with loading the javascript resources. I've had *many* issues with Google Chrome raising `load` events on external SVG resources, for example, whose DOM is not yet available. If this is the case, you might be able to `setTimeout(fn, 0)`, rather than use exception handling, as a workaround.

Comment: I was going to run your code, but I got ReferenceError: VELatLong is not defined could you jsbin or jsfiddle that?

Comment: The scope in the `for` loop is not really a separate execution context. My guess is that the variables inside the `for` loop are initialized before the loop has begun, and before `x` has any value, hence they initialize to `undefined`. When you refactored it into a separate function you set straight the order of initialization. I don't know why only Mac exhibits this behavior, though

Comment: My first thought is that you have some syntax errors in javascript. Probably some curly brackets mismatch. IE might be more forgiving and somehow resolving things. Chrome might be resolving it in a different way which may be wrong, or not resolving at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be a victim of variable hoisting http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Line 833 is probably being hoisted as its a variable name declaration within the function scope. Refactoring your variable declarations may fix the problem.

Comment: Yep, I think you are spot on, Simon. Reading the article seems to be it. The variables used are referenced everywhere and even appear to be living in the global scope.